# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object - SQL Server - simple table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've had a look at some of the other answers to this kind of question, but as a beginner, they didn't quite make sense.

Could someone please advise what I'd need to change in the queries below to prevent the error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Coding_I__C2232422662DE1EF'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Coding_Interview'. The duplicate key value is (1)

Thanks in advance.

```
create database Interview_Questions 

CREATE TABLE Coding_Interview 
(
    employee_id INT NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    position VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    department_id INT NOT NULL,
    salary INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (department_id),
    UNIQUE (employee_id)
);

INSERT INTO Coding_Interview 
    (employee_id, first_name, last_name, gender, position, department_id, salary) 
VALUES 
    (2002, 'Super', 'Man', 'M', 'Tester', 1, 75000 ),
    (2003, 'Jessica', 'Liyers', 'F', 'Architect', 1, 60000 ),
    (2004, 'Bonnie', 'Adams', 'F', 'Project Manager', 1, 80000), 
    (2005, 'James', 'Madison', 'M', 'Software Developer', 1, 55000),
    (2006, 'Michael', 'Greenback', 'M', 'Sales Assistant', 2, 85000), 
    (2007, 'Leslie', 'Peters', 'F', 'Sales Engineer', 2, 76000), 
    (2008, 'Max', 'Powers', 'M', 'Sales Representative', 2, 59000), 
    (2009, 'Stacy', 'Jacobs', 'F', 'Sales Manager', 2, 730000), 
    (2010, 'John', 'Henery', 'M', 'Sales Director', 2, 90000);
```

Comment: the error message means you are attempt to insert data with duplicate primary key, the  `department_id` and the duplicate value is `1`. I guess you must have use the wrong column as primary key. It should be `employee_id`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, Squirrel! I appreciate it. Can I just check this, please: if the department_id is the common key between this table and another table that I'd like to join to, should the department_id not be the primary key? The other table only has two columns: department_id and deparment_name. Also, would I need to create a primary key and unique ID with the first table? Or is one of them sufficient? TIA

Comment: a `primary key` should be one that can uniquely identify a row in a table. So for `department` table, the primary key should be `department_id`. In your case the table thought you name it `Coding_Interview ` it looks more like a `employee` table. And the primary key should be `employee_id`. The `department_id` column in this table is actually `foreign key` to `department` table.

Comment: Awesome! Yes - you're assumption is correct! I'd planned to change the name later. Thanks for the clarification! Last question - if I change the word "UNIQUE" in the original query to "FOREIGN KEY" like this below, I get an error saying "Expected references." Do you know why that is? TIA  CREATE TABLE employee (
  employee_id INT NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  position VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  department_id INT NOT NULL,
  salary INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (employee_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
);

Comment: please refer to documentation on the correct syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3):

First of all your table and insertion of data indicating your table has Many:1 relation with department table(assuming department table exists). In this case "employee_id" will become primary key and "department_id" will be foreign key. The other way is you can create a composite primary key based on your requirement.
You can refer this for [Foreign key creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: That link is to `Oracle PL/SQL` it will more appropriate if the link is for `SQL Server`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Squirrel. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You made the `department_id` column to be your **Primary Key**, in which your `department_id` column has repeating values in different rows. **Primary keys** are unique values to identify rows in a table and cannot appear more than once. What you did is contrary to this PK requirement. Consider making a composite or surrogate key (eg. 1, 2, 3, ...n).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone at all reading this thread or if I'm the only one who has done this. I was getting the same error as you, and the reason was because I was trying to create a new record in the database table using UPDATE instead of INSERT INTO.  I'm an amateur with SQL, so that was my bad.